# Trying to write out a variable to a file clears out the variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, variables

I want to write this to a powershell file:

```
$key='HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'
```

So I put this line into a powershell file named `run.ps1`:

```
"$key='HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'" | Out-File -FilePath C:\exp.ps1-Append
```

But when I run `run.ps1`, this is the contents of `c:\exp.ps1`:

```
='HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'
```

Why isn't `$key` being written out? I have tried surround it with two double quotes and single quotes but neither work.

Comment: `$` introduces a variable, double quotes allow for interpolating variable values. To produce that string without substituting `$key` the easiest way is to escape the `$` with a backtick: ``"`$key='HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'"``.

Comment: Very easy and works great, thanks!!

Comment: The linked duplicate contains additional information. I encourage you to either remove of fix your own answer based on Jeroen's feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out for anyone that runs into this:

```
$key2 = '$key=HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'
$key2 | Out-File -FilePath C:\exp.ps1-Append
```

Comment: Note that this is a *different* string from your original, since it's lacking single quotes around the argument. In fact this statement isn't going to work since PowerShell will try to interpret `HKCU:\...` as a command.